# "access_denied" error in the write answer at stackoverflow

Tags: support, api-v2, c#, write-access

I am providing an application (windows application), This application can search in the stackoverflow and show results. Then  User can write answer for that Question or write comment for that, Now my problem it when I want to write answer in the stack overflow i have an error it is :

> { 
>    "error_id": 403,
>   "error_message": "Applications must have a registered Stack Apps post to write",
>   "error_name": "access_denied"
>   }

more over I registered my application before also my access_token it is by write permission value.
dose some body have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a post describing your application, and edit it into your application's registration.

[image]

Basically, the first arrow needs a value; and you can set it when you edit (with the second arrow).  Click "Manage your applications" in the homepage sidebar of Stack Apps to get to your application list.

We require this so that:

- we always have a public link that identifies an app (separate from app registration)
- which we want, so users can report abuse of the API

Comment: Hello Kevin...Could you please give me example of public link from which I can get Idea about value for my app or how to render it, I have tried some values but it is giving error either as: "Post must be on stackapps" or "Post link cannot be parsed"...hoping for your answer sir..thank you